# What happens after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? (can't figure out my performance delay)

Tags: iphone, performance, view

I'm a beginning to iOS development. My objective is to reduce load-time perception during application load. I've been adding "Start" "ended" flags all over my code to try and figure out where the delay is during my application load. Below is a list of function entry points and exits. My question is:

- What's happening after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Is there a function I missed?

  ```
  1 entry: int main(int, char **)
  2 entry:  -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
  3 entry:   -[AppViewController loadView]
  3 exit :   -[AppViewController loadView]
  3 entry:   -[AppViewController viewDidLoad]
  3 exit :   -[AppViewController viewDidLoad]
  3 entry:   -[AppViewController viewWillAppear:]
  3 exit :   -[AppViewController viewWillAppear:]
  3 entry:   -[AppViewController viewDidAppear:]
  3 exit :   -[AppViewController viewDidAppear:]
  2 exit :  -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
  ? ?????:  //Here i see a VERY LONG PAUSE, possibly loading the view into memory?
            //Anyway to reduce this time here?
  //After this long delay the view actually shows up on the phone.
  ```

I'm capturing this by littering my code with macros:

- ```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
      MARKSTART;
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      MARKEND;
  }
  ```

For those that might be interested, here are my macros. Adopted from the following webpage: http://www.dizzey.com/development/ios/6-useful-objective-c-cocoa-macros/

- ```
  #define MARK      NSLog(@"----%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  #define MARKSTART NSLog(@"/===Entry: %s ===\\", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  #define MARKEND   NSLog(@"\\===Exit : %s ===/", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  ```

Additional information:

- I have many buttons in the xib file.
- Controls are skinned by replacing the background color or image with something
- PNG Image loading actually happens in viewDidLoad, the disk IO is pretty fast
- The latest delay feels like when the "view" is actually being loaded into memory, but I can't be sure.

Any advice on who i can dig deeper into this and find better ways to make my application load more quickly, or perceive that it loads more quickly? My biggest headache is the VERY LONG PAUSE... on iphone 3g (4.2.1 ios) it takes about 4.2 seconds.

Please advise,
Box

Additional Details based on Comments form the the thread. The following code in inside of ViewDidLoad. This happens very quickly taking about 200ms at the most:

```
wholeImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"DefaultSkin.png"];
CGImageRef drawImage;

drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(wholeImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480));
imageMainBackground = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage] retain];
CGImageRelease(drawImage);

drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(wholeImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480));
imageAnotherBackground = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage] retain];
CGImageRelease(drawImage);
```

I continue this, cutting up the large "whole image" into buttons and controls. Also during ViewDidLoad, I will assign them to views and subviews, like this:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[GuiSkinManager sharedSingleton].imageMainBackground]];
```

Debugging output console shows ViewDidLoad with these NSLog outputs:

```
2012-02-10 12:43:11.150 App [1714:307] Entry: -[AppViewController viewDidLoad]
2012-02-10 12:43:11.467 App [1714:307] Exit : -[AppViewController viewDidLoad]
```

So the setup and cutting is only 310ms while debugging. But the image itself is not actually processed at this time?

Comment: Have you tried pressing "pause" during the long pause and seeing what method it's in? Or time profiler instrument?

Comment: "//Here i see a VERY LONG PAUSE, possibly loading the view into memory?" – No, the view is definitely already loaded when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: @mattjgalloway: When I pause the debugger it shows me four threads. 1. Main 2._pthread_wqthread 3. __stack_chk_fail 4._pthread_start. The "VERY LONG PAUSE" lets me pause and unpause the debugger a few times. I didn't see anything beyond the assembly language. a few different pauses showed me a "gzopen" on thread 1. But nothing in the assembler that gives a hint as to what it is doing.

Comment: What method is the main thread sitting in?

Comment: @mattjgalloway I placed a breakpoint at the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: it took me into some assembler code and i pushed pause/continue a few times. Thread 1 is sitting on: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Comment: @BoxCat - no I mean when you pause it during the long pause, tell me what method the main thread is in. You can see that by opening up the main thread in the "Debug navigator" pane in Xcode.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - When i do this i see "Thread 1": The call stack (top of the list) has: imageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8bit, gzopen, png_read_filter_row, transform_preml_argb_fn... then memmove, mach_msg_trap.... when mach_msg_trap shows up, the view is loaded on the phone.

Comment: Right so it's in opening a PNG basically. Do you have some insanely large PNG in one of the views or something?

Comment: @mattjgalloway - During ViewDidLoad, I open one PNG file pretty large about 960x580. It's a skin file that i cut up and make smaller UIImages. I'll add the code above. Is there an alternative format or way of cutting this up? (i.e. 480x320 is the main background, and i have some others which are button images).

Comment: @BoxCat - It might be that, but I thought this was happening after `viewDidLoad` from your trace in your question? Or maybe you've done a dispatch back onto the main queue or a `performSelectorOnMainThread:` type thing?

Comment: @mattjgalloway - Correct, this "very long delay" is happening after viewDidLoad function is exited. Also after:  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; and the function under the AppDelegate also has exited. So some inner working of how PNG files and UIcontrols are actually loaded seems to be slowing down the App, I'm wondering if I can avoid this or dig into it and make it faster?

Comment: @BoxCat I strongly suggest using the time profiler instrument. It will reveal what methods are taking up the most time and their stack traces will lead you to see what's calling the methods.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - Thanks matt, you've been a great help. I'm not sure how to give you points? I want to. Your suggestions lead me to find that PNGs were my problem. I was using setBackgroundColor, which in-turn made the drawRect of the controls super slow once the view actually tried to load everything for the first time. After it's loaded, it's fine, but a memory hog. Adding many UIImageViews instead of setBackgroundColor improved my performance greatly. I also found that UIButtons are not as efficient as UIImageView + GestureRecognizers.

Comment: @BoxCat - I've added an answer hopefully outlining what the problem was and a bit about instruments. Hopefully that should close off this question now :-). Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that your problem is using `setBackgroundColor` instead of using a `UIImageView`. I would guess that's because `setBackgroundColor` is meant for when you're using a small image that is tiled rather than a single background image. A `UIImageView` will be super optimised for drawing a single image. I assume that's what's going on anyway.

The moral of the story here is to use instruments. It's a great tool that can really help track down a number of problems. The "Time Profiler" instrument is a great help when working out what's taking up CPU time.

Comment: Thanks matt. Yup agreed, additional moral is to stay away from setBackgroundColor using colors based on patterns.